# WPF 3D code gives blank window. How can I fix it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, graphics

TLDR: Can you tell me what is wrong with the simple "hello world" like WPF 3D app below?

Long version:

I am reading a Computer Graphics book that gives examples in WPF. In this particular example, they do not supply the full source code, but introduce the code part by part.

The only difference I have so far is that they use a `<Page>` as the root object, for which I use `<Window>`.

I am supposed to see a yellow triangle in the window, but I am seeing an empty Windows window.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Code of the MainWindow.xaml is below. After creating the WPF Windows project, I changed only this file.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="RSRCmeshPyramid"
                        Positions="0,75,0 -50,0,50 50,0,50"
                        TriangleIndices="0 1 2" />
        <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="RSRCmaterialFront" Brush="Yellow"/>
        <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="RSRCmaterialBack" Brush="Red"/>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Viewport3D >
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="57, 247, 41"
                                   LookDirection="-0.2, 0, -0.9"
                                   UpDirection="0,1,0"
                                   NearPlaneDistance="0.02"
                                   FarPlaneDistance="1000"
                                   FieldOfView="45"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <!-- scene -->
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <AmbientLight Color="White"/>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="Green" Direction="1,-1,-0.9"/>
                    <GeometryModel3D  
                            Geometry="{StaticResource RSRCmeshPyramid}"
                            Material="{StaticResource RSRCmaterialFront}"/>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>


</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring your `MeshGeometry3D` close to the origin and make your camera point at it, like below:

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication343.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication343"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="RSRCmeshPyramid"
                    Positions="0,3,0 -2,0,2 2,0,2"
                    TriangleIndices="0 1 2" />
    <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="RSRCmaterialFront" Brush="Yellow"/>
    <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="RSRCmaterialBack" Brush="Red"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>


    <Viewport3D >
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="10,10,10"
                               LookDirection="-1,-1,-1"
                               UpDirection="0,1,0"
                               NearPlaneDistance="0.02"
                               FarPlaneDistance="1000"
                               FieldOfView="45"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <!-- scene -->
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <AmbientLight Color="White"/>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="Green" Direction="1,-1,-0.9"/>
                    <GeometryModel3D  
                        Geometry="{StaticResource RSRCmeshPyramid}"
                        Material="{StaticResource RSRCmaterialFront}"/>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>

</Grid>
```